# Ionic 2 - Text overflow

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am adding text dynamically to the page

*Html*

```
<ion-item no-lines>
  <div [innerHTML] = "response"></div>
</ion-item>
```

*TS*

```
this.response = "<h3 style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;\">" + result.Response + "</h3>" + this.response; // Adding the response in new line
```

*Result*

[image]

**Problem**

1) Text is not (automatically) wrapping to next line. (See the yellow line, text is hidden)

2) What ever style I add in `innerHtml`, it is not added in the page while displaying.

How to set text-overflow/word-wrap property to solve the problem ?

P.S. I am using ionic 2 and currently testing on Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `text-wrap` to the ionic item

```
<ion-item text-wrap no-lines>
  <div [innerHTML] = "response"></div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: This one worked. Apart from this can you let me know that how can I apply css to the `innerHtml` tag/`div` ?

Comment: inspect the resulting html and try to build the proper selector... should start with .item .item-inner .....

Answer (score 1):

Just add item-text-wrap class to item.

```
<ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
    <div [innerHTML] = "response"></div>
</ion-item>
```

**or**

in this case, try to add the "white-space: normal;" property to ion-item.
By default the white-space is nowrap and that is why you see the text in ellipsis ("...")